# Why are Span<T> extension methods not implemented with the 'in' parameter modifier?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

With the release of C#7.2 came the [`in` parameter modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier) and the [`Span<T>` struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-2.2). Spans have now been flooding APIs all around .NET Core. There also was a .NET Standard API released ([System.Memory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/)) that enables usage of `Span<T>`, `ReadOnlySpan<T>`, etc.

Part of the `System.Memory` API are extension methods for these slice types, [as seen here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Memory/ref/System.Memory.cs).

The question is, why aren't these extension methods implemented using the `in` parameter modifier for the spans? Since `Span<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>` are `ref readonly struct` types, it seems like these methods would cause the runtime to create defensive copies of the spans passed into these methods. I understand that this copy is relatively inexpensive, but seems like a small performance gain would be seen.

Some .NET Core implementations of these extension methods are [located here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/MemoryExtensions.cs).

For clarification, I was expecting method signatures like this:

```
public static int IndexOf<T>(this in System.Span<T> span, T value) where T : System.IEquatable<T>
public static System.ReadOnlySpan<char> Trim(this in System.ReadOnlySpan<char> span)
public static bool IsWhiteSpace(this in System.ReadOnlySpan<char> span)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `in` has both plusses and minuses; most of the plusses are around struct copy performance, and avoiding unnecessary copies of large structs (special emphasis on the "large"), but `Span<T>` **isn't a large struct**, and in virtually all tests I've seen, using `in` on `Span<T>` has either *reduced* performance, or (less commonly) had *no impact* on performance - so even in the best case (where it doesn't degrade performance), there isn't really a reason to add it.

Comment: Can you point us to any benchmarks or write ups that back up the performance claims?

Comment: @omajid not sure if they ever got written up - a lot of these were on the fly; I could have a look through old logs, though. I *can* point you at commit comments saying to revert `in` on spans because of this, as a reminder, though :)

Comment: @omajid I'm working from memory here,so don't quote me, but IIRC the problems are thricefold: `in` adds a dereference, it reduces stack locality (making it less possible to use a register), and the JIT optimisations (for the 2-field span on core, not the 3-field span on framework) can't be applied through the extra indirection.